# Different outcomes for a single stub

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, sinon, stub

I'm using [Sinon](https://sinonjs.org) for stubbing some data retrieval methods during unit testing. Most of these data methods are async, so the `resolves` syntax has been handy so far for this. What I'm trying to achieve is to dynamically generate different test data based on `Math.random()` to cover different branches on my code automatically, without having actually to provide hardcoded sample input data for each case. Still, I've realized that the stub just is actually called once upon initialization and, not the return value of it gets fixed/constant during the execution of the testing process ([Mocha](https://mochajs.org) based). Is there any way to actually provide different outcomes for a single stub using? I've checked the onCall syntax, but it also provides fixed output, just selectable based on current iteration index, but not actual dynamic output, which could even be args/params based, perhaps.

All ideas are welcome!

Current stubbing using Sinon:

```
sinon.stub(dynamodb, 'get').resolves(stubGet())
```

The stub itself:

```
function stubGet () {
  // Choose random repo
  const i = Math.round(Math.random() * sampleData.length)
  const repo = sampleData[i]

  // Should it have "new code/push date"?
  const isNew = Math.round(Math.random()) === 1
  if (isNew) {
    repo.pushed_at = { S: '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z' }
  }

  console.log('repo', repo)
  const item = { Item: repo }
  console.log(item)
  return item
}
```

The goal would be to hopefully get the random `repo` or the `isNew` value.

Answer (score 0):

Randomness is unpredictable. Test code should be predictable, including test data. Otherwise, your tests could be failed with some random data in someday

We should write multiple test cases, each test case uses fixed, as simple as possible test data to test each branch, scene, etc. of the code. Assert whether the returned value meets your expectations.

You should make the test code, test data predictable. For more info, see [Unpredictable Test Data](https://automationpanda.com/2017/11/09/unpredictable-test-data/)

Comment: I agree, but some degree of data mutation is also useful to provide non-standard scenarios, given that there is proper control in such changes and, that's what I'm trying to achieve here

Comment: @gvasquez You should control the value of the stub by yourself rather than depend on random. From the code, I didn't see any reason you should use random data